# How do I modify my smart contract code so I'm the only one who can sell tokens? Everyone else send their tokens to me to exchange for either ETH, etc

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

So I have a token that has about 103 users. What I need to do is restrict the ability to sell those tokens to just myself the developer, so the other users can redeem their tokens for ETH or MATIC by sending to me. The alternative would be to just write a new smart contract, including this function and moving all users to the new platform. How would I write that new contract?

Answer (score 0):

The first, you can't change code of **deployed** contract in Ethereum.

The second, look at [ERC-20](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/erc20) and [ERC-721](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/erc721) (NFT) standarts, its already have functionality you need.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).